# How to record the sql command while debugging in TDengine database?

Tags: tdengine

How to record the SQL command while debugging in TDengine database?
I want to save the SQL command record in TDengine database to check If the SQL command is same as the expected. Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/taos/tao.cfg or C:\TDengine\cfg\taos.cfg file, you can change following setting

```
# enable/disable recording the SQL in taos client
# enableRecordSql    0
```

to

```
# enable/disable recording the SQL in taos client
enableRecordSql    1
```